# Решение проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: php, кодировка

Не могу решить проблему связанную с кодировкой

Этот код отправляет сообщения все нормально , все на русском.

```
mail('jenq@', 'Письмо с адрес_вашего_сайта', 'Вам написал: 
'.$name.'<br />Его номер: '.$phone.'<br />Его почта: '.$mail.'<br />Его 
сообщение: '.$message,"Content-type:text/html;charset=windows-1251");
```

А вот эта часть кода ,которая после отправки данных должна выводить страницу с ссылкой назад и текстом , а выводит иероглифы ���� ���������

```
 echo "Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено!<Br> Вы получите ответ в ближайшее время<Br> .$back";
```

Comment: Выносите ответ в ответ.

Comment: @NikolajSarry посмотрите на timestamp у правки и у ответа - ответ появился позже

Comment: @AlexanderKozin пожалуйста, оформите ответ в виде ответа, а не в виде правки вопроса - иначе ваш вопрос будет висеть без отметки и периодически будет всплывать на главной.

Comment: @NikolajSarry Хорошо , я просто пока не очень разобрался как тут работает система , я новичок )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение: Добавил в код php

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');
```